# How to hide parent ul from li level?

Tags: angular

*html component*

```
 <div class="select-wrapper select">
      <input (click)="manageOptionsView()" type="text" class="select-dropdown" data-activates="select-options-524f0174-3e9b-445a-8bf3-e304572eb476" value="Choose your option">
      <ul [ngStyle]="clickedSelect == true ? {'display':'block'} : {'display':'none'}" id="select-options-524f0174-3e9b-445a-8bf3-e304572eb476" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown">
      <li class="disabled"><span class="filtrable">Choose your option</span></li>
      <li class="" *ngFor="let option of options" (click)="changeValue(option); manageOptionsView();"><span class="filtrable">{{option}}</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

*ts component*

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.scss'],
})
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {
  clickedSelect: boolean = false;
  clickedOutside: boolean = false;
  @Input() options: any[];
  @Output() selectedOption: any = null;
  constructor(private _eref: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickout(event) {
    if (this._eref.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      this.clickedSelect = true;
    } else {
      this.clickedSelect = false;
    }
  }

  manageOptionsView() {
    this.clickedSelect = !this.clickedSelect;
  }

  changeValue(value) {
    this.selectedOption = value;
  }


}
```

As you see when i click input, ul changes display from none to block, when click outside the element ul element hides(from block to none). Ok, those functions work, but when click on li element ul doesn't change display, why?

Comment: `li` is inside `ul`,  you need to work out some logic in here `this._eref.nativeElement.contains(event.target)`

Comment: @AkhilAravind I don't how to implement it, could you show me direction

Comment: think out of the box, toggle option when the target is not  `ul`

Comment: @AkhilAravind still don't get it:)

Comment: please check the answer and confirm anser

Answer (score 0):

Was it supposed to hide?
If it is, then you could just do the same thing like you did in `manageOptionsView()`.
Set the `clickedSelect` property.

Answer (score 0):

its just a simple fix,

Change your `changeValue()` to the below code

```
changeValue(value) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.clickedSelect = !this.clickedSelect;
    this.selectedOption = value;
  }
```

[Check out the stackblitz snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xun6mz)